# Validating timezone in Java and throwing exception

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Is there any function in joda.time which validates a string whether it represents correct time zone or not and throws a exception if it is not in the correct format?

I am aware of TimeZone.getAvalibaleIDs() but just curious to know if there is any predefined function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DateTimeZone.forID()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forID%28java.lang.String%29) will throw an exception if the ID isn't recognized.

That's appropriate if you're trying to get the actual zone - if you're *just* trying to validate whether an ID is valid or not, I'd use [`getAvailableIDs()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29):

```
boolean valid = DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs().contains(id);
```

That's better in terms of avoiding using exceptions for flow control, IMO. However, they're *not* equivalent - fixed-offset time zone IDs are valid in `DateTimeZone.forID()`, but may not be included in the set of available IDs.

Comment: I found DateTimeZone does not have PST as a Id. But java.util.TimeZone has it.

Comment: @Harshana: That makes sense - PST isn't an IANA ID. `java.util.TimeZone` has a bunch of "features" that leave a bit to be desired. You should find the appropriate time zone ID for what you want, e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`. (But not necessarily that one...)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Process [`ZoneId.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) under `try/catch` and catch the exception for the invalid timezone ID.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                "America/New_York",
                "GMT",
                "UTC",
                "UCT",
                "GMT+01:00",
                "UTC+01:00",
                "ABC"
        ).forEach(s -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(ZoneId.of(s));
            } catch (ZoneRulesException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
America/New_York
GMT
UTC
UCT
GMT+01:00
UTC+01:00
Unknown time-zone ID: ABC
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rimHnV)

I do not recommend `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().contains(time-zone-id)` because it may fail for some cases as shown below:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "America/New_York", "GMT", "UTC", "UCT", "GMT+01:00", "UTC+01:00", "ABC" };

        // Alternatively
        Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(s -> System.out.println(allZones.contains(s) ? s : ("Unknown time-zone ID: " + s)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
America/New_York
GMT
UTC
UCT
Unknown time-zone ID: GMT+01:00
Unknown time-zone ID: UTC+01:00
Unknown time-zone ID: ABC
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/R0zHAq)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can write a piece of function like below instead of using Joda:

```
private boolean isTimeZoneValid(String givenTimeZone) {
    Set timeZoneSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()));
    return timeZoneSet.contains(givenTimeZone); 
}
```